# Expo run on android emulator using windows 10

Tags: android, react-native, expo

Can I run android emulator without an android phone? I have installed android studio and I've already installed android virtual device. However, when I try to run it, it gives an error like this :

> Couldn't start project on Android: Error running adb: No Android
>   device found. Please connect a device and follow the instructions here
>   to enable USB debugging:
>   https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html#developer-device-options.
>   If you are using Genymotion go to Settings -> ADB, select "Use custom
>   Android SDK tools", and point it at your Android SDK directory.

I just want to see the emulator in my pc without usb. I have an iPhone but it just shows up in my phone not in my pc using expo scan barcode. I don't want to do that because in my opinion it's not comfortable for debugging etc. I am using windows in my pc so I can't use iOS for emulator.

**how to run expo android emulator on windows?**

Comment: emulator normal start type in path folder :`C:\Users\[YourUserName]\AppData\Local\Android\SDK/emulator/emulator`

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Yes you can:-(With zero android studio config)

1. Install expo-cli globally.
2. Install android Studio.
3. Create a project by running expo-cli init
4. No need of any configuration on android Studio.
5. Open existing Project from android studio

[image: Open the expo project]

6. then Open the created expo Project it will be available as an android project with a 
   android logo on it
7. then open the AVD Manager
   [image: run avd manager]
8. Download and install whichever device you want but see to that its above android N 
   and do it for x86
9. after Installing the desired emulator

[image]

10. run the emulator before running the project
11. then run     expo start     to start the Project
12. Go to the metro builder and say run android
    [image]
13. if it doesn't run on the first go or if you get error close the project 
     from emulator from recents  and do a run on android again from metro 
    builder don't close project just the running project from recent on emulator

[image: from here]

14. then it should work

Comment: How can this be approved pixel 2 with android pie 9.0 has no reaction with this.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me, just take time to start the android emulator, so just wait.

Comment: This works ! could u also explain how to build an apk locally using expo

Comment: For neophytes like me who are confused about step 12: Metro Bundler (not "metro builder") is called "Expo DevTools" in the console output when you run your Expo app. By default, it is accessible at http://localhost:19002

Answer (score 12):

Maybe too late, but I found out that is simplier that what you think.

1. Install your Android SDK (studio)
2. Create new emulator: Go to Tools > AVD Manager > Create new virtual device
   (I chosen Nexus, Android 7)
3. When you get new emulator installed try to find out list of it ( command: `emulator -list-avds` )
4. !! If you do not have emulator in the path follow this commands in PowerShell:

```
    PATH = %PATH%;C:\Users\[YOURUSERPCNAME]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
    PATH= %PATH%;C:\Users\[YOURUSERPCNAME]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator
    PATH= %PATH%;C:\Users\[YOURUSERPCNAME]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin
```

5. Run your emulator: `emulator -avd [NAMEOFYOUREMULATOR]` from the command `emulator -list-avds`
6. When emulator runing go to your Expo root folder (wher package.json is) and run `npm start`
7. Click on run in Run on Android device/emulator

Enjoy coding

**Edit for Linux users**

my linux usecase is as follow:

1. Install Android studio and open it
2. Install any emulator using AVD manager and try it's working
3. Close studio and go to your android folder `~/Android/Sdk/(two options 'emulator/' or 'tools/')`, basically you need to find emulator
4. list item `./emulator -list-avds`
5. choose your emulator and run it `./emulator -avd <any emulator>`
   if emulator not work use sudo
   if you do not get any options in Sdk folder but you installed emualtor than you did it propably as a superuser - then the easiest is to completely remove all android studio and install it again

Answer (score 4):

There is another way to solve this problem. Follow the steps below in the same order:

1. run `expo start` to start the Project
2. Wait for the metro builder to be displayed in the browser.
3. On the terminal, wait for all options to be displayed, like so: `To run the app with live reloading, choose one of:`
4. Now load a device from `Android Virtual Device` in `Android Studio` (which already has the folder containing expo project open). On the terminal, press the key `a`.

Then the app should now open on the device being emulated.

Answer (score 3):

Delete the directory C:\Users\Rizwan.expo\android-apk-cache and opening the project on android again
It will run