# errors after running expo start

Tags: react-native, expo

I have installed latest node version and expo-cli but when I run the command `expo start`, it gives me this error:

```
Starting project at C:\Users\Ogacho\Desktop\sharelocation
Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19002
Your project is in SDK version >= 33.0.0, but the expo package version seems to be older.
Opening DevTools in the browser... (press shift-d to disable)
Error: React Native is not installed. Please run `npm install` in your project directory.
Couldn't start project. Please fix the errors and restart the project.
Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.
```

I have tried clearing my npm cache, deleting my node_modules folder and reinstalling...

Comment: [the Same Question are Solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52751874/11741753) 
            https://stackoverflow.com/q/52751874/11741753

Answer (score 4):

This fixed it for me:

Run `expo update 35.0.0.` (Replace version with your desired version. 35.0.0 is the latest as of this post.) This updates expo, by updating app.json & package.json and installing the latest dependencies.

Referenced from:

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/upgrading-expo-sdk-walkthrough/

Also, check that:

- your expo app is the latest version through the app/play store.
- your expo cli is the latest version `npm install -g expo-cli`

Answer (score 2):

Your project is in SDK version >= 33.0.0, but the expo package version seems to be older. If your expo-cli version is older than 2.21.2, run `npm install -g expo-cli` to get the latest version.

Or, you can change sdkVersion and dependencies to an older version to match the expo-cli [doc](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/upgrading-expo-sdk-walkthrough/).Run `expo --version` to get the expo-cli version. **For example**, if using expo-cli 2.19.5, you should

- `app.json`, change `sdkVersion` to "32.0.0",
- In package.json, change these dependencies:

```
{
  "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
  "expo": "^32.0.0",
  "react": "16.5.0"
}
```

- Delete your project’s node_modules directory and install again

Comment: thanks that solved my first piece of the puzzle but now i get this error Error: Problem validating fields in app.json. See https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/workflow/configuration/
 • Field: platforms - should NOT have more than 2 items. and adb verision(40) is not compatible with client(41)

Comment: Would you mind showing your app.json content here? There must be something wrong. Here is my platform value:  "platforms": [
            "ios",
            "android"
        ],

Answer (score -1):

Close your Expo CLI server
Run `expo upgrade` in your project directory (requires the latest version of expo-cli, you can update with `npm i -g expo-cli`).
Make sure to check the breaking changes section of this post!
Run `expo start -c`